# Divider issue in android xml layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, divider, buttonbar

[image: sample]

My goal is to get the layout like the sample about. However, I can't get the small line above the button bar.

What I get is like this.

[image]

my xml code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    >

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_above="@+id/buttonBarLayout"
      android:showDividers="middle"
      android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal">

    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Section header"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
        android:dividerPadding="8dp">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
          android:text="Sample item 1"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
          style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
        android:dividerPadding="8dp">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
          android:text="Sample item 2"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
          style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/buttonBarLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      style="?android:buttonBarStyle"
      >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Discard"
        style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Save"
        style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I believe that the line is the middle divider. However, if I use LinearLayout the divider will show right under Sample item 2, which is not what I want.

So how can I get what the sample shows?

Comment: You may use `<View />` to add divider between two buttons.

Comment: @Owen Zhao: the answer provided by Hamid Shatu does not fills the divider width completely. It leaves some margin on left and right. Plus the width is set to 0 dip which makes it invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra `View` to your layout which will take no `height` as below...

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip" />
```

Then add the above `View` and the `Linearlayout` which holding `Buttons` inside another `LinearLayout` with `android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"` attribute as below...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        style="?android:buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Discard" />

        <Button
            style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, your layout will be...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonBarLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <TextView
            style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Section header" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:dividerPadding="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:showDividers="middle" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Sample item 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

            <ImageButton
                style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
            android:dividerPadding="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:showDividers="middle" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Sample item 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

            <ImageButton
                style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip" />

        <LinearLayout
            style="?android:buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Discard" />

            <Button
                style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Save" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Resulted Layout:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    >

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_above="@+id/buttonBarLayout"
      android:showDividers="middle"
      android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal">

    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Section header"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
        android:dividerPadding="8dp">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
          android:text="Sample item 1"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
          style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
        android:dividerPadding="8dp">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
          android:text="Sample item 2"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
          style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/buttonBarLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:orientation="Vertical"
      style="?android:buttonBarStyle"
      >
      <View android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_widht="match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/buttonBarLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
      style="?android:buttonBarStyle"
      >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Discard"
        style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Save"
        style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

  </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this below layout. I've made few changes to add the horizontal divider above ButtonBarLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_above="@+id/buttonBarLayout"
  android:showDividers="middle"
  android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
  android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="24dp" >

<TextView
    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Section header"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="8dp">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
      android:text="Sample item 1"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

  <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="8dp">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
      android:text="Sample item 2"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

  <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonBarLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  style="?android:buttonBarStyle">

  <View
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:background="#F1F1F1" />

  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  style="?android:buttonBarStyle">

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Discard"
    style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Save"
    style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the id to the Linear layout above the button linear layout and place the view in between the button linear layout and linear layout above it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp">

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layout1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_above="@+id/buttonBarLayout"
      android:showDividers="middle"
      android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal">

    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Section header"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
        android:dividerPadding="8dp">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
          android:text="Sample item 1"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
          style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
        android:dividerPadding="8dp">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
          android:text="Sample item 2"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
          style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>


  <View
       android:id="@+id/view1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
 android:background="#000000" />

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/buttonBarLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

      android:orientation="horizontal"
      style="?android:buttonBarStyle">



    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Discard"
        style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Save"
        style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```